# How can I include the user id inside of a shortcode php output?

Tags: php, shortcode, comments

For the shortcode I am using, the developer of the plugin only added the ability to output content via the shortcode. So the shortcode is all I have to work with.

Here is the default shortcode which does work:

```
echo do_shortcode("[theplugin_user_data user_id='8']");
```

With this code, it will output the data for the user with user id of "8". Problem is I can't use this code because if I put that it would give the same data for user id "8" to all comments, while I need it to fetch for each commenter.

So basically I need to fetch the user id of the current comment author, and after fetching their id I need to insert it dynamically into the shortcode.

Here is an idea of what I can come up with but I don't know how to make it work.

```
echo do_shortcode("[theplugin_user_data user_id='" . phpcodehere . "']");
```

So how can I get the current commenter's user id and insert it into the shortcode shown above?

---

***Note:***
I am putting this in the comments section to pull the data. I am using the default wordpress comments system, no plugins or external comments system (the plugin I am pulling data from doesn't have anything to do with comments).

***Note 2:***
The user ID that is needed is the commenter who MADE the comment, not who is logged in -- please note that this is inside a wordpress comments loop pulling all comments. Here is the comment loop:

```
function theme_comment( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
```

*For example, `get_comment_author_link()` works inside the loop to get the link for the comment author. What I need is the user ID of the comment author.*

***Note 3:***
Not the post author, nor the logged in user; what I need is the comment author user ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm assuming the "current commenter" is actually the current user logged into WP. So to get the current user ID, you can simply use [get_current_user_id](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/):

```
echo do_shortcode("[theplugin_user_data user_id='" . get_current_user_id() . "']");
```

**UPDATE**

Ok, so we want, then, the comment's author ID:

```
//$comment = get_comment(); // in your case, it seems you already have a $comment object...
if($comment) {
    if($comment->user_id) echo do_shortcode("[theplugin_user_data user_id='" . $comment->user_id . "']");
    else echo '(no data available)'; // <---- fallback, in case the comment has no known author
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nope, current commenter is NOT the current user logged into wordpress. It was the user who made the comment! :) Please revise accordingly

Comment: Updated question with further details.

Comment: **NOTE:** I did try `" . get_current_user_id() . "` and that method **does work for inserting php into the shortcode**; now all I need is the correct call to get the **comment author user ID**, not the current logged in user.

Comment: Yep - just updated my answer

Comment: Now I've got a problem. I noticed that it isn't fetching the correct user id every time. On some comments it is the correct id, but other comments it is the wrong id. How do I fix that?

Comment: How about you show us your comment loop, so we know exactly in what context the code will run? Thanks!

Comment: `function theme_comment( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
 $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
`

Comment: To test I echoed the user id and I see for some users it's showing a user ID of `0`

Comment: Right - if your site is setup to allow anonymous comments, then those will not have an author ID. Only comments left by logged-in users will have a user_id - that's why the `if` in the code I gave you. Now, based on the small snippet of code you gave me, you already have a $comment object handy - so you don't need `$comment = get_comment();`... Other than that, though, the code I gave you will always give you the current $comment's author ID

Comment: I thought the same except that there is a user id of `0` for some registered users also. Edit: actually I thought this user was registered but that was just a website link. I think you are right. How can I workaround this issue? **EDIT** I don't allow anonymous comments. Users must enter email and username in order to comment.

Comment: Yes but if you don't require them to be logged-in, WP has no user ID to assign their comments...

Comment: It's the "Users must be registered and logged in to comment " checkbox you need to activate if you don't want non-logged-in users to comment

Comment: How can I make it so if the user id is 0 (null) then it does something different?

Comment: Update my answer for the case where you don't have a known author

Comment: Great! Thank you for all your help! :D I did an alternate if statement where `if ($comment->user_id != 0) { echo do_shortcode( ... ) }  else {  echo "none"; }` but same thing, seems like this is the solution. Thank you!